# Cannot create Angular application http-server - Error: css and js files 404 Not found

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, httpserver

I want to create a PWA but the http-server package doesn't work.

So I've created a default Angular-App with `ng new myProject` and then created the `dist`-folder with `ng build --prod`

Now all is set so I `cd` into the `dist`-folder and run the npm package `http-server -o` the first site opens and I click on the link but then I get a lot of error messages. The site remains blank (completely white), where there should be the Heroes-Demo of the Angular CLI.

```
[Wed Jul 03 2019 10:37:24 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] "GET /styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css" Error (404): "Not found"
[Wed Jul 03 2019 10:37:24 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] "GET /runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js" Error (404): "Not found"
[Wed Jul 03 2019 10:37:24 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] "GET /polyfills-es2015.27661dfa98f6332c27dc.js" Error (404): "Not found"
[Wed Jul 03 2019 10:37:24 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] "GET /main-es2015.79588c7e85ca7a0dacf0.js" Error (404): "Not found"
```

So I've not even been able to get the site working, what might be the problem?

Here is the entire Log:

```
$ http-server -o
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://159.144.42.198:8080
  http://192.168.34.113:8080
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
[Wed Jul 03 2019 10:37:24 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] "GET /styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
[Wed Jul 03 2019 10:37:24 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] "GET /runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
[Wed Jul 03 2019 10:37:24 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] "GET /polyfills-es2015.27661dfa98f6332c27dc.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
[Wed Jul 03 2019 10:37:24 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] "GET /main-es2015.79588c7e85ca7a0dacf0.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
[Wed Jul 03 2019 10:37:24 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] "GET /styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css" Error (404): "Not found"
[Wed Jul 03 2019 10:37:24 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] "GET /runtime-es2015.858f8dd898b75fe86926.js" Error (404): "Not found"
[Wed Jul 03 2019 10:37:24 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] "GET /polyfills-es2015.27661dfa98f6332c27dc.js" Error (404): "Not found"
[Wed Jul 03 2019 10:37:24 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)] "GET /main-es2015.79588c7e85ca7a0dacf0.js" Error (404): "Not found"
```

Comment: What's the content of the `dist` folder`?

Comment: A bunch of files, but the ones that give me the error described above are actually there, so their not missing but the web-app seems unable to get them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your angular app is an SPA, you need to reroute each request to the `index.html`.

With `http-server` you can use the proxy parameter for it, for example:

```
http-server --proxy http://localhost:8080?
```

It's also mentioned in the `http-server` [README](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server#catch-all-redirect).

Comment: That would be true if the OP refreshed the page when on a different route than /, but the problem here is not getting static assets that should be served by http-server. I agree the question is confusing, but I don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: Sorry, what can I do to make the question more clear? I've posted the full contend of the Log and the error if that helps..

Comment: I've tried doing ``http-server --proxy http://localhost:8080? -o`` and now I don't get the errors anymore, however the page is still blank, so this didn't work..

Comment: @Miger post a minimal but complete example reproducing the problem. Post the output of `ls` when you're inside the dist folder. Tell how you reproduce the problem (when clicking on which link? what's the code f that link?). The code matters.

Comment: I literally didn't touch the code at all, it's all the default Angular-App. You make a new Project with ``ng new your-project`` then you run ``ng build --prod``, this will create the ``dist``-folder and there you run ``http-server -o`` I've not done anything else so far. That's why I'm stuck.

Comment: Doing that wouldn't store the application under dist, but under dist/your-project. Unless you're using a very old version of the CLI/Angular. So I guess that you were not telling us the truth when we asked "what's the content of dist" and you answered "a bunch of files". You need to run http-server from dist/your-project. That's where the bunch of files actually is. dist only contain a single directory named your-project. BTW, I asked you to post the output of `ls` when you're inside the dist folder, and you didn't. This would have made the problem clear from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry about the ``ls`` thing. I knew there was a subfolder but I thought the command needs to be run inside the ``dist``-folder so I didn't think it was relevant to give you the ``ls``-output.. you figured it out, it works now - so, thank you very much :)